# Create mail lock in perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a perl script as cron to send mails to me if a certain condition is met. I am doing this to run every 15 mins. However, I want to limit my script from generating a mail when it has sent a mail in the last 60 mins.

Here's the code snippet i am using to achieve that, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
use strict;

my $Mailed = 0;
if ( !-f `/tmp/Mail.lock` ) {
    $Mailed = 1;
}
else {
    my $om = `find /tmp/Mail.lock -mmin +60`;
    if ($om) {
        $Mailed = 1;
    }
}
if ( $Mailed = 1 ) {
    print "Starting " . Now() . "\n";
    print "send mail";
}
```

Am i missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error #1

```
-f `/tmp/Mail.lock`
```

should be

```
-f '/tmp/Mail.lock'
```

The former tries to execute `/tmp/Mail.lock`, and tests if the result (`undef`) is the name of an plain file.

This problem have been discovered by `use warnings;`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

---

### Error #2

```
if ( $Mailed = 1 ) {
```

should be

```
if ( $Mailed == 1 ) {
```

What you have assigns `1` to `$Mailed`, then checks if it's true (which it obviously is).

Actually, it should be the following:

```
if ( $Mailed ) {
```

There's no need to check for which specific true value `$Mailed` has.

This problem have been discovered by `use warnings;`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

---

Fixed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant ACTIVITY_QFN => '/tmp/Mail.lock';
use constant COOL_DOWN    => 60*60;

my $mail = 0;
my $mtime = ( stat(ACTIVITY_QFN) )[9];
if (!defined($mtime)) {
   die("Can't stat activity file ".ACTIVITY_QFN.": $!\n")
      if !$!{ENOENT};

   # Activitiy file doesn't exist.
   $mail = 1;
} else {
   $mail = 1 if time() >= $mtime + COOL_DOWN;
}

if ($mail) {
   utime(undef, undef, ACTIVITY_QFN) 
      or warn("Can't touch activity file ".ACTIVITY_QFN.": $!\n");

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added use warnings to my script and it showed me where the errors were. I proceeded to correct them. Most of the corrections reflect what you guys have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on `warnings` too, and you'll get:

```
Found = in conditional, should be == at  line 12.
```

Basically - your 'test' doesn't work at all. What are are evaluating is 'did I set `$Mailed` to `1`' and funnily enough it's always working.

Try this snippet:

```
my $Mailed = 0;
if ( $Mailed = 1 ) { print "Yes\n"; }
```

`Now()` isn't a real function either. Maybe you were thinking of `time()`?

Also - you are testing the text output of `find` there, rather than the return code. But either way, calling `find` for a single file, from a perl script is overkill anyway.

I'd also suggest - rather than calling out to `find` - instead just write to the file and read the `mtime` via stat.

e.g.:

```
my $mtime = ( stat($filename) )[9]

next if $mtime > time() - 3600;
```

Or alternatively, use the '-M' operator:

```
my $send_inhibit = 1 / 24; # 1 hour in days, because -M $filename returns in days. 
next if -M $filename < $send_inhibit;
```

Creating the file (when you send a mail) via:

```
open ( my $lockfile, ">", $filename ) or die $!;
print {$lockfile} time();
close ( $lockfile );
```

Comment: For the purpose of `-M` is a day always 24 hours?